# HTML table cell width vs clientWidth

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

A peeve of mine is having to create a table of data that does not scroll the contents. I have seen a few implementations, but they all com short for various reasons; the main one being I want one of the columns to expand to fill the available space.

So I have created two tables. One for the header and associated text and one for the actual data.

I have a javascript method that gets called whenever the screen is resized to set the overflow-y on the table. If the screen is tall enough to accommodate all data, I hide the scrollbar and set the display to 'none'.

Other wise, I have to set overflow to 'auto' and display to 'block'. This all works as expected, but it changes the column widths.

So I decide to set each cell's width property of the data table to the clintWidth of each cell in the header table.

The width is being set as expected, but the clientWidth is not being recalculated.

```
    $(window).resize(sizePanels);

    function sizePanels() {
        var dataTable = document.getElementById("tblData");
        if (dataTable != null) {
            try {
                var itemHeight = 0;
                if (dataTable.rows.length > 0)
                    itemHeight = dataTable.rows[0].clientHeight;

                var itemHeight = itemHeight * dataTable.rows.length;
                var rect = dataTable.getBoundingClientRect();
                var screenHeight = document.body.clientHeight - rect.top - /*document.body.topMargin - document.body.bottomMargin -*/ 50;
                if (screenHeight < 100)
                    screenHeight = 100;

                var headerTable = document.getElementById("tblHeader");
                //var padCol = document.getElementById("padCol");
                if (itemHeight <= screenHeight) {
                    screenHeight = itemHeight;
                    //padCol.style.display = "none";
                    dataTable.style.display = "";
                    dataTable.style.overflow = "visible";
                }
                else if (dataTable.rows.length > 4) {
                    //padCol.style.display = "";
                    dataTable.style.display = "block";
                    dataTable.style.overflow = "auto";

                    var cells = headerTable.rows[0].cells;
                    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i) {
                        dataTable.rows[0].cells[i].width = cells[i].clientWidth;//.toString() + "px";
                    }
                }

                dataTable.style.height = screenHeight + "px";
            }
            catch (exception) {
            }
        }

        return (dataTable != null);
    }
```

Here is my HTML, I am using Angular:

```
        <table id="tblHeader" class="headerLayout" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="100px">First Name</th>
                    <th width="100px">Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th width="75">Products</th>
                    <th width="75">Manager</th>
                    <th width="50">Actions</th>
                    <th width="60"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <table id="tblData" class="headerLayout" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;">
            <div ng-init="sizePanels();"></div>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="user in Users | filter:filterUsers">
                    <td width="100px">{{user.FirstName}}</td>
                    <td width="100px">{{user.LastName}}</td>
                    <td width="100%">{{user.Email}}</td>
                    <td width="75">
                        <a href="#/users/addproductskills/{{user.UserId}}"><img src="\Content\images\AssignDoc.gif" style="padding-left: 17px; padding-bottom: 2px; cursor: pointer" /></a>
                    </td>
                    <td height="25px" width="75">
                        <buton class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="openManagerDialog(user);">Assign<i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i></buton>
                    </td>
                    <td height="25px" width="50">
                        <buton class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="openEditDialog(user);">Edit<i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i></buton>
                    </td>
                    <td height="25px" width="60">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="deleteUser(user)">Delete<i class="fa fa-remove pull-right"></i></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

the `<div>` tag within the data table is to call the JavaScript function when the content is first loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, the issue was with the 100% width on the second column of the data table! My idea was to use it as a place holder.

Thanks for taking a look!